# Powershell script only works in ISE

Tags: shell, powershell, ssh, scripting, sh

**DESCRIPTION**
So I have this script, where I login to remote machine using OpenSSH in powershell script. It creates the session and executes `~Run_Project.sh` and logs to the log file in the linux machine `> ~/project_log&`.

```
function StartSSHsessionAndRunProject
{

    try
    {
        ssh.exe -i ~/id_rsa-private remoteLinuxMachine@admin '~/Run_Project.sh > ~/project_log&'

        if ($?)
        {
            Write-Host "SSH session has been created...`n" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else
        {
            throw $error[0].Exception
        }
    }
}
```

**EXPECTATION**
As you can see I have '&' symbol at the end of the > ~/project_log& command. It supposed to return to the if statement.

**PROBLEM:**
This script works fine and as expected in Powershell ISE. However, when I debug or run this powershell script in another tool like Visual Studio Code, Run As Admin in Powershell command DOESN'T work. Anything before this function works fine, the script just pauses and looks like it freezes in ssh.exe line. However, it actually runs the project and the project log says it has started. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running PowerShell.exe with the -STA switch?

Comment: How can you use the switch statement in this case?

Comment: @Hashim77 It is a switch for the PowerShell.exe program itself. e.g. `PowerShell.exe -STA`